# Як правильно перекласти The "Subjectname" Handbook effort

Tags: переклад, from-english

Маю наступну фразу: *The Gentoo Handbook effort*, схиляюсь до варіанту: *"Настільна книга Gentoo"*, але можливо є якісь більш власне українські варіанти?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Слово "Handbook" - означає "посібник" або "довідник".
Я би переклав дану фразу як "Посібник користувача Gentoo" або "Спроба написати посібник користувача Gentoo"

Answer (score 5):

оскільки це саме handbook **effort**, то можливо сенс можна передати [наслідуючи Кобзаря](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) і перекласти як "Захалявна книжечка про %Subjectname%"

Comment: "Захалявна книжечка" — не надто пасуватиме до офіційної технічної документації.

Comment: Я відштовхувався від того, що Handbook - це такий стислий довідник по певній темі, який завжди під рукою. А effort підкреслює намагання його скласти, певну недовершеність

Comment: @AntonLinevych Трошки гумору не завадить. От і приклади -  `The UNIX Hater’s Handbook`, `Mr. Bunny's Guide to ActiveX`, `Pretending to know javascript`

Comment: @Yola також зустрічаеться `Learn you %topic% for a greater good`. але саме **офіційність** дійсно контрастує з _інтимністю_ захалявної книжечки